# Prevent Overlayed Text on Image from Fading

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how to keep overlay text at full opacity while making the image behind the text partially opaque. Here's my code:

```css
.shadow { box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12); }

.caption {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.supporter {
  margin: 20px;
}

.redi {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  width: 94%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.damp {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<div class="card shadow">
  <img src="my-img.png" class="damp" alt="my-img">
  <p class="caption black">title</p>
  <p class="supporter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <div class="redi">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">See link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text nicely sits on top of the bottom left corner of the image. My problem is when I change the opacity of the image behind the text, the text also fades.

#### Stuff I've tried already:

- `z-index: -1;` on image
- `opacity: 1;` on text

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the negative `z-index` work, you need to add a non-`static` `position` value. Here I've added `position: relative; z-index: -1;` to the image and that does it.

Instead of a negative `z-index`, you could also add `position: relative` to the overlayed text and it will give that text a default `z-index` higher than the image.

```css
.shadow { box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12); }

.caption {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.supporter {
  margin: 20px;
}

.redi {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  width: 94%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.damp {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card shadow">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="damp" alt="my-img">
  <p class="caption black">title</p>
  <p class="supporter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <div class="redi">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">See link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up using `position:relative` on the caption. Thanks!

Comment: @The_Grits good choice! A negative z-index is goofy and can cause issues.